# Sliding Glass Door Mortise Lock Replacement

Tags: doors, outdoor, lock, sliding-glass-door

I live in Florida and I have a Hurricane sliding door there the lock has failed. I thought that this would be an easy thing to replace, but when I removed the screws to take the lock out, there is a metal bar behind the lock that prevents the lock from sliding down or up (I had to force it to where it is now). The metal bar probably goes up the whole length of the sliding door. I think that the only way to fix this is to remove the door from the track, lay the door down, loosen the bottom bolts then and remove / angle the side out. (I had to do this to replace the rollers a few years ago).

Anyone have any experience with this? Am I missing something simple or is my path forward the correct one?
[image]

Comment: Are there strike plates in the top and/or bottom of this door's frame?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, no there are no strike plates at the top or bottom. I did take the sliding door off to try and slide the lock out of the top or bottom but it will not move. I also tried to take the lock off of the other sliding door and it has the same exact issue. Not too sure what to do here. I can't imagine how they got the lock in the door!

Comment: Got it out. I had to rotate the lock 90 degrees of the vertical plane. I can't believe that the door needs to come off and apart in order to do this!

Comment: Post that as an answer and I'll give it a +1 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to replace this lock, I needed to take the door off the track and then dismantle the aluminum frame with a block of 2x4. Once apart, I unscrewed the locking mechanics and then rotated the lock 90 degrees inside the aluminum channel and slid it to the top. (It would not come out of the bottom.) To replace the lock, I followed the same process in reverse.

It's a shame that the whole door had to come apart to replace a $12-13 part. But I am glad it is done. If pictures are needed for someone else, I will be more than happy to post some.

Comment: This is great info for others in this situation, thanks for coming back to post it. Be sure to give yourself a check-mark! I'm just guessing, but if this "Hurricane" door is designed to be hurricane resistant, and that's not just a brand name or model, it may be that this method improves the strength and impact resistance of the door/lock mechanism to help protect your house in a storm. That's probably a higher priority than ease of repair in a part that probably doesn't fail all that often.

Comment: @FreeMan, exactly. The house was built in 2007, so 13-14 years on the same lock is acceptable to me. Now the door rollers and track, that's a separate issue that requires more frequent attention. And technically, I did not have to take the door apart. I could have taken the door off the track, rotated the lock, removed the lock from the top of the door, then reinstalled. Probably a lot less risk than taking the side panel off and then having the "smash" it back on.